# Issues with Printf() and fgets()

Tags: c

I am working on creating a project that has a custom header file, and ran into some problems:

I'm not exactly sure what happened to this code, but after I started using the `fgets()` function, it seems to have stopped the output of some `printf()`'s in my code.  Here are the important parts of the code, probably missing some `#include` statements here:

`main.cpp`

```
#include "ichat.h"

int main() {

     prompts(P_IDLE, response);
     prompts(P_USERNAME, response);
}
```

`ichat.cpp`

```
#include "ichat.h"
int prompts(int p_tag, char *response) {

    if (p_tag == P_IDLE) {

        printf("\nWaiting for connections. Press [ENTER] to start a chat.");
        char msg[50];
        char *ptr;
        while (true) {

            fgets(msg, strlen(msg), stdin);
            ptr = (char*)memchr(msg, '\n', strlen(msg));
            if (ptr != NULL) {

                break;
            }

    } else if (p_tag == P_USERNAME) {

        printf("\nPlease enter a username you'd like to use: ");
        ....

    } ...
```

some of `ichat.h`, incase you were curious...

```
#define P_IDLE 0
#define P_USERNAME 1
```

compiled with `gcc main.cpp ichat.cpp`.

The issue is that when adding in the while loop with the `fgets()` function, none of the `printf()` functions produce output in the command line. I'm not exactly sure what is happening here, because those print functions were working, and sometimes they work if I remove the `\n`, or if I add another `printf()` function right before them.  It's pretty confusing...

Is there a better way to get input from the user?  I'm open to any hints, critiques, and ideas about any part of my code.

Comment: You wrote "implementing the `fgets()` function". That sounds like you're writing your own version of `fgets()`, but the code looks like you're just calling it. Please update your question to clarify that.

Comment: What do you expect strlen to return when you are passing it to fgets? Why are you tagging this c++ if you are using printf and fgets instead of iostreams?

Comment: `strlen()` is passing the length of the string `msg` to that function, I think. I was using `printf` and `fgets` because it was consistent with a book I was reading on this topic.  I could transition it to iostreams, do you think it would help?

Comment: `strlen(msg)` --> `sizeof msg`

Comment: Note that one item of information missing in `main.cpp` is the definition of `response`.  Ideally, you should show that — and it shouldn't be a global or file scope variable.  Also, the design of your `prompts()` function should pass the size of the response buffer to the function so you can ensure no buffer overflows.  You should check the response from (value returned by) `fgets()` — your code would probably loop indefinitely on receiving EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nub of your problem is

```
char msg[50];
 /* no initialisation of data in msg */
fgets(msg, strlen(msg), stdin);
```

`msg` is uninitialised, so the values of any of the characters in it are indeterminate - they are not guaranteed to be zero.   Formally, even accessing their values (which `strlen()` does to search for a `'\0'`) gives undefined behaviour.

What you need to do is change `strlen(msg)` to `sizeof msg`  (which will consistently give the value of `50`).

`fgets()` will modify `msg` based on input.   Then you can use `strlen()` on the result.

Also:  try not to use `(char *)` type conversions on the result of functions like `memchr()` that return `void *`.  It is only needed in C if you have forgotten to `#include <string.h>`.  Including the right header is the better solution than the type conversion.    If your C compiler is actually a C++ compiler, the conversion will be needed, but C++ provides alternative approaches that are often preferable (more type safe, etc).

Comment: would you be able to give some of those C++ approaches?  I'd like to know how to improve this code if possible.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve, obviously.    In general terms, C++'s `std::string` is a string type, and its a standard container, so can be searched by standard algorithms.  If you want more specific advice, state exactly what you're trying to do and ask a C++ tagged question.    There are plenty of people who will be able to give useful advice.   Do a bit of legwork first though (e.g. read up on C++ string type and standard algorithms) - people will be more inclined to help if you've demonstrated an effort first.